# Leaflet — point in which polygon? Rtree?

Tags: leaflet, r-tree

Does leaflet provide a method for determining which, if any, rendered point is within a polygon? Not by iterating over a bunch of shapes and checking bounds, but by using an rtree index, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Leaflet plugins page](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html), on which you'll find [leaflet point-in-polygon](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) and [Leaflet.LayerIndex](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.LayerIndex).